# I get "list index out of range" for a boolean but not when I use that boolean in a for and if loop?

Tags: python, list, if-statement

I have written a function which, when given a list of integers, returns True when the list argument contains a 3 next to a 3 somewhere. Here is my code:

```
def has_33(nums):
    for i,num in enumerate(nums):
        if nums[0]==3 and nums[1]==3:
            return True
        elif nums[i+1]==3 and (nums[i+2]==3 or nums[i]==3):
            return True
        else:
           return False
```

This function either returns True or False even though I realised

```
nums[i+1]
```

could be out of range when the loop reaches the last index.

E.g if I have a list defined as `nums=[1,3,4,5]`, the function returns `False`.
However, when I separately run

```
nums[4]==1
```

I get "IndexError: list index out of range" which I understand why but I don't understand why, in the function,

```
nums[i+1] or (nums[i+2] or nums[i]==3)
```

doesn't throw the same error when it reaches the last index of the list?

Comment: You never finish the loop, you are returning false in your first iteration.

Comment: Just for fun a different approach: `return '3,3' in ','.join(str(v) for v in nums)`

Comment: @Matthias Just for fun, you don't need the `,`

Comment: @ChatterOne You do, or else [33,1,2,4,5,6] would return true :)

Comment: @Loocid Yes, isn't that what we're looking for?

Comment: @ChatterOne Not as far as I understand. They want 2 threes in a row, not 1 thirty three.

Comment: @Loocid yes correct

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Loop through the list and just check if there is a '3' at index i and i+1. You need to be sure you loop till `(length of list -1)`, so that there won't be any `indexoutofrange` exception when you access i+1.

```
def has_33(nums):
    for i in range(len(nums)-1):
       if(nums[i]==3 and nums[i+1]== 3):
        return True
    return False

print(has_33([3,3,3,4,5,3,3,4]))
```

Comment: You might want to explain why you changed the code the way you did. Just dumping code won't be helpful for future readers.

Comment: Thank you for this insight. I have added description.

Answer (score 1):

The function does not throw the `IndexError` because it never reaches the last element of the list.

In the first iteration if evaluates condition 1 and 2, both are false so it goes into the `else` returning `False`, and no more iterations are performed.

If you try with `nums = [1, ]` you actually get the IndexError. The beahavior you are looking for is achieved moving `return False` outside the loop:

```
def has_33(nums):
    for i, num in enumerate(nums):
        if nums[0]==3 and nums[1]==3:
            return True
        elif nums[i+1]==3 and (nums[i+2]==3 or nums[i]==3):
            return True
    return False   # <- this is outside the for loop
```

This way it cycles every element in the nums list. However you are right saying that your code will throw an `IndexError` every time the list do not contain a pair of 3's. A safer way would be to skip the first iteration and look for the element and its previous. A safer an more pythonic way would be to use the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) function in one line of code (I don't want to spoil the solution, if interested reply with a comment).